# Custom Vector class jump on uninitialised value

Tags: c++

im trying to create a custom vector class in c++. As im quite new to the whole c++ world im a bit confused. Valgrind is telling me that im doing a jump on an uninitialised value. However I don't know why that appears.

My personal answer would be alright i dont initialize any values in the normal

```
vector(unsigned startCap = 1, unsigned increment = 0):
        width(increment),
        cap(startCap),
        field(new T[startCap]){};
```

However im completely clueless as this happens during the use of my operator= where i compare *this with my input.

Maybe someone could be so clever and tell me what i should do here.

```
template<class T>
class vector{
public:
    vector(unsigned startCap = 1, unsigned increment = 0):
        width(increment),
        cap(startCap),
        field(new T[startCap]){};
    ~vector(){
        delete[] field;
    };
    vector(const vector& x):width(0),cap(1),field(new T[1]){
        copyHelper(x);
    };
    vector(const T& x):width(0),cap(1),field(new T[1]){
        push_back(x);
    }
    void copyHelper(const vector &v) {
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < next; ++i) {
            setField(v,i);
        }
    }

    void push_back(T x){
        if(next >= cap)
            resize();
        getField()[next++]=x;
    }
    T& operator[](unsigned x){
        return getField()[x];
    };

    const T& operator[](unsigned x) const {
        if(x < size()) {
            return getField()[x];
        }
    }

    bool operator==(const vector<T> v) const{
        if((getCap() == v.getCap()) && (getNext() == v.getNext()) && (getWidth() == v.getWidth())){
            for(unsigned i = 0; i<v.getCap();++i){
                if(getField()[i] != v.getField()[i]){
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    vector& operator=(const vector& x){
        if(*this == x)
            return *this;
        setCap(x.getCap());
        setNext(x.getNext());
        copyHelper(x);
        return *this;
    };

    T* getField() const{
        return field;
    }

    void setField(const vector<T>& x,unsigned i){
        field[i] = x.getField()[i];
    }

    void setField(const T* x){
        field = x;
    }

...
private:

    void resize(){
        const unsigned newCap = width == 0 ? cap * 2 : cap + width;
        T* newField  = new T[newCap];
        for(unsigned i = 0; i<cap;++i){
            newField[i] = field[i];
        }
        delete[] field;
        cap = newCap;
        field = newField;
    }
    const unsigned width;
    unsigned cap;
    unsigned next = 0;
    T* field = nullptr;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of problems with this code.

Most notably, your `operator==` has some logic errors in it. But more importantly, `if(*this == x)` in `operator=` should be `if(this == &x)` instead.

Also, your copy constructor is implemented wrong. It allocates room for only 1 element, but then attempts to copy as many elements are in the source vector.

And, your const `operator[]` is missing a `return` or `throw` if the input `x` is out of bounds. It should not be performing anyvbounds checking at all, like your non-const `operator[]`.

And, `setField()` looks like a memory leak waiting to happen.

And, we can't even see the rest of your implementation, so there is no way to see if there are other problems.